# Django retrieve data from db to complete a url pattern

Tags: django, django-urls

I know this is an easy question, I am just not getting something...so thank you for your patience and advice.

I have a view that asks a user to register to use our app.  The data he/she submits is stored in a database and he is sent off to another page to set up the application:

```
#views.py

def regPage(request, id=None):
    form = RegForm(request.POST or None,
                       instance=id and UserRegistration.objects.get(id=id))

    # Save new/edited pick
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dev/leaguepage/')
    user_info = UserRegistration.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'user_info' :user_info,
    }

    return render(request, 'regpage.html', context)
```

Rather than sending ALL users to the same page '/dev/leaguepage/', I need to send each user to his own page based on the PK in the database like: '/dev/PrimaryKey/'  I am not sure how to make this happen either on the views file or in the URLs.py file:

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from acme.dc_django import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^leaguepage/$','acme.dc_django.views.leaguePage'),




    url(r'^$', 'acme.dc_django.views.regPage'),
)
```

Thank you for your help!

dp

Updated code:

```
#url
  url(r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/$','acme.dc_django.views.leaguePage', name="league_page"),

#view
  def regPage(request, id):
    form = RegForm(request.POST)

    # Save new/edited pick
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('league_page', kwargs={'id' :id}))
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/dev/leaguepage/')
    user_info = UserRegistration.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'user_info' :user_info,
    }

    return render(request, 'regpage.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a reverse lookup on your leaguePage to do your redirect, passing in the values you need to resolve the pattern. You'll need to add a name to the URL pattern you want to reverse, but basically the syntax is:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_detail', args=(), kwargs={'id' : id}))
```

Example URL pattern and view:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('my_app.views',
    url(r'^my-pattern/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'my_action', name='my_detail'),
)

def my_action(request, id):
    #do something
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would have to write the pattern in the urls.py page then use the reverse code here to feed the args/kwargs to it to get the response I want.

Comment: That's correct. I'll augment my answer with an example of the URL.

Comment: I hate to be a pest, but when I implemented your suggestion, I got an error: `regPage() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`  I will update the above with the exact code i am using in my view and url.  I have only been working with Django for a month or so and I find the urls the most challenging part...

Comment: No worries. Glad you got things figured out. It's a bit older book, but you might check out Practical Django Projects. I found that book really helpful when getting started.